# check storage engine from shell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

I'm upgrading to 3.0 and ran into some issues with the upgrade. Specifically, I got an error when trying to start up `mongod` via `ssh`, it tried to use the default `dbpath` instead of the one I specified in my new YAML config file. I went ahead and rebooted the machine and now `mongod` is up and running again. I'm a bit paranoid at this point and would like to know if there's a way to make sure the storage engine is `wiredtiger` from the shell.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Easiest way to find the storage engine being used currently.**

Inside mongo console type

```
db.serverStatus().storageEngine
```

It returns the storage engine being used currently

```
{ "name" : "wiredTiger" }
```

Once it is confirmed that wiredTiger is being used then type

```
db.serverStatus().wiredTiger
```

to get all the configuration details of wiredTiger.

Comment: Just to confirm, this works on Windows, too.

Comment: db.serverStatus().storageEngine for this command I got output as wiredTiger. But wiredTiger section is missing when I run db.serverStatus() and also many other metrices are missing.  mongodb version is 4.4.4 I am using mongodb Atlas and connecting through following command: 
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.4dkyu.mongodb.net/admin" --username veeresh1

Comment: I got answer to the doubt I had. There are some limitations on free cluster and M2/M5 shared clusters. [reference link](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/unsupported-commands/)

Answer (score 10):

**DISCLAIMER : Not a MongoDB Expert**

Check the process list in Linux

```
WIREDTIGER_CONFIGURED=`ps -ef|grep mongod|grep -i storageengine|grep -ic wiredtiger`
echo ${WIREDTIGER_CONFIGURED}
```

1 means it's there

From the mongo shell

```
db.serverStatus()
```

You should see something like this

```
"wiredTiger" : {
   ...
   "cache" : {
      "tracked dirty bytes in the cache" : <num>,
      "bytes currently in the cache" : <num>,
      "maximum bytes configured" : <num>,
      "bytes read into cache" :<num>,
```

or you can just pull the storage engine name with

```
db.serverStatus().storageEngine.name
```

You will either get `mmapv1` or `wiredTiger`

or from the command line

```
MONGO_ENGINE=`mongo -u... -p... --eval "db.serverStatus().storageEngine.name"`
```

Comment: I'm on ubuntu, so I tried the Linux command and it showed 0, but the db.serverStatus() shows a wiredTiger node.

Comment: well either way, the db.serverStatus is encouraging. with this i'll go ahead and update my other servers and put in a ticket with mongo for a definitive  answer.

Comment: any update on this? I still get a 0 when I run this.

Comment: @chaitanya.varanasi Please look at the other answer. It has what you want. For the sake of clarity, I will say this: If you are running MongoDB 3.x, just run `db.serverStatus().storageEngine.name`. It will either say `mmapv1` or `wiredTiger`.

Comment: Grepping for the `--storageEngine` parameter only works in limited situations, e.g. MongoDB 3.0 where the parameter is explicitly provided on the command line. Typically `mongod` configuration values are provided in a configuration file so they won't appear in the `ps` output. In MongoDB 3.2+ WiredTiger is the default storage engine so no additional parameter is required. The recommended approach to use is your second suggestion of `db.serverStatus().storageEngine.name` via the `mongo` shell. FYI, if you happen to be using MongoDB 2.6 or older this won't work: the only storage engine was MMAP.

Comment: @Stennie Please note that the question has a mongodb-3.0 tag. This is why I answered the question specific to 3.0.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Fair enough, just noting version caveats here since some earlier comments relate to the `ps | grep` approach not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `mongod.log` file gets populated by a string which describes what  storage engine you're using;
so you could run:

```
cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log  | grep STORAGE | tail -n 1
```

which returns something like:

```
2017-06-28T21:45:24.745+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=4G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
```